# I don't know how to solve a compilation error (VHDL error 10344)

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl, quartus

I am a beginner in vhdl. I wrote a code about an 8 bit adder. When I start compilation it has one error that I don't know how to solve it. I may have other errors in my code that I can't notice. Here is my code :

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity Adder_plus is 
  generic (size: integer :=8);
  port( x,y: in std_logic_vector(size-1 downto 0);
        sum: out std_logic_vector(size-1 downto 0);
         c_out: out std_logic );
end Adder_plus;

architecture RTL of Adder_plus is
  signal s: std_logic_vector(size downto 0);
  begin
    s <= std_logic_vector("0" & unsigned(x) + "0" & unsigned(y)); --I wrote it this way because it does not recognise "+" 
    sum <= s(size-1 downto 0);
    c_out <= s(size);
end RTL;
```

Here is the error tha appears:

```
Error (10344): VHDL expression error at Adder_plus.vhd(16): expression has 17 elements, but must have 9 elements
```

Comment: I tried you code in Vivado and it gave a fatal run time error in that line. But passed after I added parenthesis to make sure the right parts are held together: `("0" & unsigned(x)) + ("0" & unsigned(y))` As brackets do not 'cost' anything it is good practice to use them and you are sure the code does what you expect it to do.

Comment: You may be better served learning operator precedence rules instead of adding parentheses by rote. Adding operators (here + and &) are the same precedence and are evaluated left to right. "0" & unsigned(x) + "0" is valid, the shorter length operand is resized. "0" & unsigned(x) + ("0" & unsigned(y)) gives you matching elements for the right hand expression and the assignment target. There are a couple of places superfluous parentheses can be problematic.